# Is sponsor ad expired for excel tag? If yes then remove the free space

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags

It's look like sponsorship on tag [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) is expired. So the advertisement is removed. But the space is not removed.

Before few days (or may be till 31<sup>st</sup> Dec. 2012) the advertisement was like this:

> [image]

But now it is not showing ad and also the free space is not removed.

> [image]

<sup>PS: I cleared my cache but the space is still there.</sup>

Comment: That box there is supposed to be filled in by adzerk, but their script doesn't appear to be actually putting anything there.

Comment: @Shog the bug (blank space) [wasn't fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167218/blank-space-in-kendo-ui).

Comment: @Sha looks good to me.

Comment: @Shog but what if tag sponsorship will expire again? In my opinion real fix would be avoiding such situation in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fret not, vigilant user-- the tag sponsorships expired on 12/31 and some were not automatically extended, requiring explicit confirmation from clients that they want to continue sponsoring tags.

They've been updated on our end, and should start serving soon.

Thanks for keeping an eye out!

---

Edit: live now!

Comment: What to do if the sponsorship expires again? Do I need to report it once again (by asking a question)? or Just leave a comment here?

Comment: @hims056 for this tag, report it here. We now have a tool in place to prevent this from happening in the future, but sometimes things slip through the cracks. In those cases, it really helps a lot when you guys let us know! So: thank you!

Comment: [NoSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql) tag is not showing anything right now.

Comment: @hims056 are you sure? I'm seeing Neo4j there.

Comment: Actually I was not able to see adv from my PC. But I can see it from my mobile. :)

Comment: Haha gotcha. Thanks for keeping an eye out!