# white space with heroku tag search

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

when looking for question tagged with heroku - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku

I get a big useless white area above the Heroku description. I am using chrome 23.0.1271.97

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161030/is-sponsor-ad-expired-for-excel-tag-if-yes-then-remove-the-free-space, apparently the sponsorships have expired. Or adzerk is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Manishearth notes above, the tag sponsorships expired on 12/31 and some were not automatically extended. As a result, we need to receive explicit confirmation from clients that they want to continue sponsoring tags before setting them live.

All has been updated on our end, so they should start serving soon.

Thanks for keeping an eye out!

---

Edit: live now!