# Blank space in Kendo UI

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags

When clicking on the Kendo UI tag, it just shows a [big blank div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kendo-ui):

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: its fine when i click on other  Sponsored  tag  ..

Comment: Their sponsorship probably expired then and is awaiting action.

Comment: @animuson is correct, the sponsorship was awaiting action. In this case, it needed to be turned off. Thanks for keeping an eye out!