# Medium blank gap between navigation and tag description

Tags: bug, sponsored-tags

There is a medium-sized gap between the navigation area and the tag description, for a (or possibly a few) tag(s).

This seems to happens on sponsored tags (e.g. [google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension)), but not others (e.g. [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)).

As of 2013-03-08 on Chrome/Firefox/IE9 (date is [ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/)-compliant)

Happens on [google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension):
[image: Tag google-chrome-extension]

But not on [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):
[image: Tag javascript]

Note: Adblock is not enabled.

Comment: Yep, same here. @MartijnPieters Given that I don't use an ad-blocker, it doesn't seem to be a duplicate. Or am I missing a point?

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, but I mentioned that Adblock is **not** enabled and the "suggested solution" over there is "disable advertisement blockers".

Comment: I seem to recall a post where this space was still reserved for ads waiting for renewal? Edit: Ah, found it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161030/is-sponsor-ad-expired-for-excel-tag-if-yes-then-remove-the-free-space

Comment: Ah, indeed, there is no advertisement there today. My mistake.

Comment: @Bart seems to make sense, but it's not a good idea to leave an empty space there. Why don't collapse it instead? (Yes, this is the point.)

Comment: Why did you black out publicly available information about your profile?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby To prevent looking into the past easily from the future.

Comment: @AlvinWong: Mmmhhh...sounds legit.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby oscillation.