# Webp tag doesn't have a sponsored advert like other 'special' tags

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, tags, sponsored-tags

See this picture below, found when clicking on [webp](/questions/tagged/webp).

[image]

This tag is a sponsored one. Normally they have an associated 'advert' (served by the ad engine anyway) like [android](/questions/tagged/android), but this doesn't.

I guess something should be there, or the white space shouldn't.

Comment: Adblock is disabled. Ads show for other special tags just fine.

Comment: I've now removed adblock from chrome (and restarted) and have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161030/152859) as the sponsorship has probably expired. @Bolt can you please cast your Close As Dupe magic? :)

Comment: Should they handle the case where the sponsorship isn't renewed straight away to hide the issue from users though?

Comment: That's what I would expect, and also suggested it in a [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161030/is-sponsor-ad-expired-for-excel-tag-if-yes-then-remove-the-free-space#comment490787_161030). As it stands now, they do it manually every time. (extending or cancelling the sponsorship)

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot that one. Guess it is a dupe, shame it's status completed though.

Comment: Yeah, they fixed only that specific case with that specific tag.