# Does the logo in the tag info page stay even after the sponsorship ends?

Tags: support, advertising, sponsored-tags

If I buy a tag sponsorship on Stack Overflow, then even after my ads stop running, will my logo on the tags remain? Or do I have to have the ads ongoing, renewing every 30 days?

Comment: I think you have to renew it if it is subscription based. If it is one time payment, then there'll be no issues

Comment: @i-- it's not permanent, it expires at some point, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161176/152859) for "proof". :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I buy a tag sponsorship on Stack Overflow, then even after my ads stop running, will my logo on the tags remain?

Of course not. No ad service in the world operates by keeping ads going after the customer stopped paying. This is essentially asking "Will I keep getting the service after I've stopped paying for it?".

You can see details of the tag sponsorship product here:

https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise/solutions/tag-sponsorship

If you select to "Buy Now", the options are for either:

- Ongoing, renewing every 30 days
- Run for specific dates

Which means - if you go with the first option, yes, you need to renew in order for the tag to retain your logo.

If with the second option, the tag will have your logo for the dates you have chosen and paid for.